# Replace values in a pandas dataframe given values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Given this dataframe, I am trying to find all cells that start with NA, and replace the

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'NA_1', 'NA_2'), 'Val': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)})
      A  Val
0     a    1
1     b    2
2     c    3
3     d    4
4     e    5
5  NA_1    6
6  NA_2    7
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
      A  Val
0     a    1
1     b    2
2     c    3
3     d    4
4     e    5
5  NA_1    -100
6  NA_2    -100
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
s = df.replace('NA_1', 100).drop('Val', 1).ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]
print(s)
df.Val = np.where(s.isnull(), df.Val, s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda functions like so:

```
df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda x: -100 if 'NA' in x['A'] else x['Val'], axis=1)
```